# Content Staging - any ideas?

Tags: staging

We have a customer who is looking for a way to do content staging, or in other words prepare larger packages of content on a staging system and then transfer them to the production system at a certain time.

As far as I know there is no mechanism that fulfills this requirement in a convenient way. Am I right?

What I have heard before:

- FeedMe (nice tool, but not ideal for migrating clean content from another system)
- GraphQL API: could be done, but probably a lot of manual interaction or preparation

Does anybody know other ways to handle that?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you’ve considered, and discounted, relying on publish dates, toggling entries to be live/disabled, and only showing certain content to logged in users.

So the only other thing I can think of is a multi-site installation. Set up two sites, staging and production, make sure staging is password protected and blocking bots, then do everything on the staging site, when the client’s happy make it live on the production site as well.

There may well be a more elegant solution, and you’re really at the mercy of the client’s discipline to not break everything (which they inevitably will), but I think it would work.

Comment: we already use multi-sites massively for content organisation and it should definitely be another machine as we can not deploy to production that often (very strict IT rules)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, unfortunately there is no great solution (neither first or third party) currently.

Best I can do is let you know it's on the radar. As of writing, *releases* aka "batched content releases" is planned for a Craft 5.x release, as per [the official roadmap](https://craftcms.com/roadmap).

As Craft is on a yearly major release cycle since 4.0, Craft 5.0 is expected to drop sometime in 2023 (likely Q3 or Q4). Whether this feature will make it into the 5.0 release or not is unknown though.

For reference, see the Github issues related to the roadmap item:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/12255
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/8941
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/11661

Comment: Thanks Mats for your answer, I am also looking forward for the batched content releases in Craft 5. As mentioned in the other comment above, my problem is deployment cycles on production. we prepare new features and would also like to start preparing content as early as possible. and at that time, the features, fields etc. are not yet on production....

Comment: Aha, if you want to deploy schema changes (i.e. project config) and publish new content at the same time, that goes beyond the use case for batched content releases I think. You should probably look into [content migrations](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/migrations.html). Although you'd still need to devise some kind of workflow for the actual export and import for the new content from your staging database to production; wrapping it in a migration would at least provide a robust mechanism for deploying schema and content changes at the same time.